# Размер экрана приложения определяется на iPhone X не на весь экран?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios11, iphone-x

Создаю UITextView через размер MainScreen bounds, во всех эмуляторах окно приложения занимает полностью весь экран, а в iPhone X экран приложения меньше чем доступная высота экрана, над и под окном приложения - неиспользуемые черные полосы, как растянуть окно приложения из кода на весь экран?

```
#import 'ViewController.h'
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize myTextView;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.myTextView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake (0, 0,[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width,[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height)];

    myTextView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    myTextView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeAll;
    myTextView.scrollEnabled = YES;
    myTextView.editable = NO;
    self.myTextView.text = @'bla... bla... bla....';
    self.myTextView.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14.0f];
    self.myTextView.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    myTextView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [self.view addSubview:myTextView];
    [self preferredStatusBarStyle];
}
```

[image: Вот screenShot эмулятора iPhone SE]

[image: Вот screenShot эмулятора iPhone X]

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "MainNavigationController.h"



@interface AppDelegate ()

@end

@implementation AppDelegate


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    ViewController *viewController = [[ViewController alloc] init];
    MainNavigationController *mainNavigationController = [[MainNavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds]];
    self.window.rootViewController = mainNavigationController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: LaunchImage используете?

Comment: Нет,  LaunchImage не используется. Голый app. Вызываю только строки указанные в ViewDidLoad

Comment: Можете прикрепить проект с этой проблемой?

Comment: Вот добавил еще содержание AppDelegate.

Comment: Вот, нашел, оказывается xCode добавил default LaunchImage 568h@2x.  Как этот LaunchImage изменить чтобы исправить ситуацию с iPhone-X?

Answer (score 2):

Замените LaunchImage на LaunchScreen. Создайте его, New file ->:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В Project -> General установите его:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Большое СПАСИБО! Все получилось :)))